# TestFlight says dSYM missing (formerly: CFBundleExecutable missing from IPA).

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, testflight

I have an iOS app (my first) I am preparing to beta test via TestFlight. I followed the steps in TestFlight's tutorial for creating an IPA, but then the TestFlight desktop uploader complained "dSYM not found". Upon researching this, here on SO, I saw a couple different questions relating to having targets that were still set to build armv6 under Xcode 4.5. I checked my Xcode settings, and for both the product and my one compiled target (I have 3 or 4 script targets) "Valid Architectures" is set to "armv7, armv7s". I remember having to mess with this when I upgraded to Xcode 4.5, and I think I changed it then. I am building Cocos2d as a sub-project and I checked it as well. The only other archive I have is the libTestFlight.a, which is of course pre-built. I unzipped my IPA, looked in the Info.plist, and CFBundleExecutable is in fact missing, though Bundle Name, Bundle Display Name, and Executable File are all there and correct. What else could cause this? Could there be a problem with codesigning or my Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile? I have made some changes to make my bundle identifier consistent with my App ID on iTunes Connect (a case-sensitivity issue).

Edit: I did in fact have a correct CFBundleExecutable. I was using PListEdit Pro to look at the Info.plist, and what it was reporting as "Executable File" was really CFBundleExecutable. I also took my ad-hoc signed IPA and used Xcode organizer to install it on my device, and it runs just fine, so there is no problem with the IPA, other than the TestFlight desktop app cannot find the dSYM in it. I unpacked the IPA, and it does seem that the dSYM is missing. I looked in the .xcarchive I built the IPA from, and the dSYM is present in there, so it looks like it is being stripped out by the codesigning step, perhaps? I extracted the dSYM from the xcarchive and attempted to upload it with my IPA to TestFlight. The IPA was uploaded correctly, but it does not appear the dSYM was uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this was an issue with the Beta version of the TestFlight desktop app. I could upload the same IPA using the web interface with no errors, though I had to separately upload the dSYM file. It would be great if someone from TestFlight could comment on this one way or the other.